# Deploying a Java fat jar with embedded apache Derby database

Tags: java, maven, deployment, derby, executable-jar

I have a desktop Java application that I'm developing that has an embedded Apache Derby database ([Link](https://github.com/stuie382/Tournament-Database)) . Now, when I run the application through my IDE, everything works great and functions as expected. However when I create the fat jar (including all the dependencies), when I launch the application it boots fine, but I get the following error message:
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema 'TDB' does not exist

To me, this suggests that the schema I have created has not been copied across into my new jar file, but in that case I'm not sure if I'm creating my jar correctly.

What I would like it to do is when I run the package goal of my pom, it will create a new jar, with all of the dependencies included, that I could effectively give to someone else and they could run it as a fully functional desktop application (in the same way I can run it through my IDE, just without the IDE).

Any help would be massively appreciated, I've been banging my head against this one for a few days now.

Stu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see it there are two approaches to this:

1. You determine the file system location of your database files and make sure it is included in your deployment - this should be do-able from within the IDE
2. You include a start-up process that check if the database is present, and if not creates the schema on the fly

Comment: Option two sounds the more robust option. Given that I have all the SQL necessary to recreate my schema in src/main/scripts (movable as it is currently just there as a reference), is there a way to include the scripts so that they are run from the pom as part of the jar creation - this would make each jar a fresh copy of the database. Or would I have to achieve this another way? I really don't know that much about Maven yet to know if that is possible?

Thanks

Comment: Ok so I have it working when I grab the files created by Derby (a directory called 'Tournament') and stick that and the fat jar in the same directory. When I then run the jar, everything appears to be working how it should.

This is not quite the solution I was looking for, however it will do for now unless someone can come up with what I originally wanted.